# I want to implement python trained .h5 model in java,but getting errors while importing it

Tags: hdf5, deeplearning4j

```
String simpleMlp = new ClassPathResource(
                          "semantic.h5").getFile().getPath();
MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.
                    importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(simpleMlp);
```

i used the above code for implementation and i am getting this below error. can anyone suggest what is wrong with this

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File with name semantic.h5 does not exist.
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasModelBuilder.checkForExistence(KerasModelBuilder.java:356)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasModelBuilder.modelHdf5Filename(KerasModelBuilder.java:228)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:217)
    at DeepLearning.main(DeepLearning.java:24)
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious what is wrong - `File with name semantic.h5 does not exist.` Try to specify absolute path to this file

Comment: i tried using and absolute path but it didn't work.then i added this semantic.h5 in resources